# Load tibble to environment does not work as expected

Tags: r, environment, rlang

From this simple piece of code

```r
df = tibble(A = 1)
save(df, file = file.path("tmp.RData"))
df = tibble(A = 2)
# tmp <- rlang::env()
tmp <- environment()
load("tmp.RData", envir = tmp)
```

I would expect `df` to contain 2 and `tmp$df` to contain 1, but both do contain 1, so the loaded `df` overwrites the one from the global environment.
This is not the behaviour I expect passing the `envir` argument to `load`.

Can someone explain me the reason why ? Am I missing some important design here ?

NB: replacing the base R `environment` with `rlang::env` it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `environment()` returns the current environment; it does not create a new environment. Here you can see it's just the global environment

```
tmp <- environment()
tmp
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

so you are replacing the value of `df` in the global environment.

If you want a new environment, use

```
tmp <- new.env()
load("tmp.RData", envir = tmp)
```

That will load into a different environment and keep the value of `df` in the global environment untouched.

Comment: How could I miss this? Sorry for the noob question, and thanks for your answer